# Hide mat select after I select an option from the dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I need to add an extra option to the dynamic options that are being added to Mat-Select.

Once I choose "Other" as the option I want the mat-select to be hidden and a text area to appear where i can add a reason. The catch is that this mat-select will be duplicated for n number of items so it should only hide the mat-select for the item of which selected option is OTHER.

Right now onSelectOthers() doesn't do anything I was just testing out ways to solve this problem.

```
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let itemCancellationReason of systemService.itemCancellationReasons"
        [value]="itemCancellationReason.value">{{ itemCancellationReason.value }}
      </mat-option>
      <mat-option (click)="onSelectOthers()" value = 'OTHER'>OTHER</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Comment: You can use the `[ngClass]` directive to apply a style class name to an element based on a bound expression - in this case whether the selected value equals the special value "OTHER". I question why you'd want to hide the select control, though; how will the user change back to a non-OTHER option if they change their mind?

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the appearance of the text input using a style using the `ngClass` directive bound to an expression that tests for the special OTHER value being selected.

**component.html:**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Make a selection:</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectedItem">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item">
      {{item}}
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="OTHER_OPTION">{{OTHER_OPTION}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" [ngClass]="{ 'hidden': selectedItem != OTHER_OPTION }">
  <mat-label>Enter other option:</mat-label>
  <input matInput />
</mat-form-field>
```

**component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  readonly OTHER_OPTION = 'OTHER';
  selectedItem?: string;
  options = ['foo', 'bar', 'bazz'];
}
```

**component.css:**

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

You can also hide the select in the same way (with the comparison inverted) although IMO that might not be great for the user.

Here is the Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ldwf6p?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Used almost the same Code that u wrote here but it still shows me the input every time

      `<mat-option
        *ngFor="let itemCancellationReason of systemService.itemCancellationReasons"
        [value]="itemCancellationReason.value">{{ itemCancellationReason.value }}
      </mat-option>
      <mat-option [value]="OTHER_OPTION">{{OTHER_OPTION}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" [ngClass]="{ 'hidden': selectedItem != OTHER_OPTION }">
    <mat-label>Enter other option:</mat-label>
    <input matInput />
  </mat-form-field>`

Comment: Did you add the hidden class to the CSS? I have now added that to the answer in case it wasn't obvious.

Comment: FYI you can see all the files in the Stackblitz.